# Using AutoMapper inside Onion Architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, automapper, onion-architecture

We are implementing an aspnetcore web api application using the onion architecture. I have the following rings:

- Domain
- Application
- Infrastructure
- Dependency Resolver

So far we have managed to keep all third party implementations in the infrastructure layer while inserting a generic interface in the lower rings where we need that functionality.

However, we now have to start using AutoMapper and here is where I am getting a little confused how to implement it. In our app, the lowest ring where we need mappers is the application ring. This is the ring that contains all the DTOs. In my mind, if we are sticking to this architecture, AutoMapper implementation should be in the infrastructure layer and then we can inject it's IMapper interface, or wrap that interface with a slightly more generic interface (just containing a couple of Map(SourceT src, TargetT trg) methods), into the inner ring(s). All good so far. The confusion comes when I think about the mapping configuration. Since there is no generic way to setup this mapping (the CreateMap()), it seems like it should be in the infrastructure layer, however, logically, if I add another DTO to the application ring why should I have to go to infrastructure layer to creating the mapping for it. The configuration seems like it should be on the application ring, but in that case, I would have to depend on Automapper.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Something like AutoMapper involves two different classes, obviously, usually crossing app layer boundaries. For example, you might map an database entity in your DAL layer to a DTO class in your business layer. As such, the place for that code is where those boundaries intersect.

For example, if Infrastructure has a dependency on Domain, and you're mapping classes between domain and Infrastructure, then the place for the AutoMapper code is in Infrastructure, since both layers are available. Likewise, if you have a view model in your Application layer, being mapped from a class in your Infrastructure layer, then the place for the AutoMapper code is in your Application layer. Again, because that is where there is involvment of both layers.

Long and short, there's not just one place. Each layer should house the mapping code relevant to that layer.

Comment: I understood what you are saying, but when you mention "mapping code", are you talking about the mapping of the objects (IMapper.Map()) and the mapping configuration (CreateMap)? Is your approach to always keep those two together? Or do you keep one "profile" at the highest level to creating mapping for all objects that need to be mapped.

Comment: Both, the actual mapping and the configuration, such as any profiles you create, yes, should exist together. Again, you need both classes, so that must exist at the layer boundary, you can't just cram everything in one layer, as not everything is available at that one layer.

Comment: That works for me, however, it still leaves me with my original question. If I need mapping in my application ring, my application ring will need to be dependent on AutoMapper (a third party tool) because I will need to create the mapping profile there. Application ring should not be dependent on infrastructure ring.

Comment: Downvoting this question because no layers other than Infrastructure should know about the technology involved. I agree with @User20909