# Configure Mapper and create DTO for ViewModel -ASP.NET Core 6 Web API #Clean Architecture

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dto, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-6.0, mapper

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project, based on clean architecture containing these layers :

[image: clean architecture]

I want to add DTO for view models and configure mapper (like demanded). I have already added entities in the domain layer, and the project is well configured to database and I'm using Entity Framework.

I want to know in my case, I create folder DTO under domain layer containing same content as entities? Or creating view models (I want to understand more about view models) and then creating DTO for these view models.

I want just a simple example like this: get method in this architecture

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230151/using-automapper-inside-onion-architecture) can give you some help.